# Iterating Through A List Doesn't Check Each Object

Tags: c#

```
if (rowCount[i] >= 10)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < blocks.Count; j++)
    {
        if (blocks[j].Row == i)
        {
            blocks.RemoveAt(j);
            rowCount[i]--;
        }
    }
    foreach (Block b in blocks)
    {
        if (b.Row < i)
        {
            b.Row++;
            rowCount[b.Row]++;
        }
    }
}
```

So say I have 20 blocks in the blocklist.  I went through the program line-by-line debugging, and I saw that it doesn't check through each block in the list- it usually leaves around 4 or 5 unchecked.  Am I going crazy or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Probably because you're removing items from the list but not adjusting your iterator (`j`).

Comment: Are you sure everything in `blocks` is of type `Block`?

Comment: How should I adjust my iterator?

Comment: Better to go backwards through the list...

Comment: Very bad idea to be changing a list as you iterate over it.. that is, removing items.

Comment: This is the third time I've seen this mistake on SO. Usually the form I see is `for (j = 0; j < queue.Count; ++j) queue.Dequeue();` Do you see why this removes only half the items in the queue?

Comment: @Baldrick: Better to not go through the list in the first place! You can't make a mistake in your loop condition if you don't write any loops.

Comment: @EricLippert: Agreed. Your solution is far cleaner. 2 lines of code and no loops makes the code a LOT safer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are decreasing the size of the array as you loop over it so if you remove index 4, index 5 becomes the new index 4 and you never check it.

The two ways to fix it is either decrement your iterator

```
if (rowCount[i] >= 10)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < blocks.Count; j++)
    {
        if (blocks[j].Row == i)
        {
            blocks.RemoveAt(j);
            rowCount[i]--;
            j--;
        }
    }
    foreach (Block b in blocks)
    {
        if (b.Row < i)
        {
            b.Row++;
            rowCount[b.Row]++;
        }
    }
}
```

or loop in reverse order

```
if (rowCount[i] >= 10)
{
    for (int j = blocks.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (blocks[j].Row == i)
        {
            blocks.RemoveAt(j);
            rowCount[i]--;
        }
    }
    foreach (Block b in blocks)
    {
        if (b.Row < i)
        {
            b.Row++;
            rowCount[b.Row]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, it works!  Thanks very much.  I read a book on XNA and it had lists for all the lasers in the game, and it would use the same method of checking a boolean condition in a for loop, but it wouldn't decrement the iteration variable.  Bad habits instilled too early.

Answer (score 10):

A better solution to the accepted solution is to break it down differently. You want to do two things in that first loop: decrease `rowcount[i]` by the number of matches, and remove the matching rows from the list. Now, how would you do that without *any* loops? The first is easy:

```
rowCount[i] -= blocks.Where(block=>block.Row == i).Count();
```

Done. The second is easy too:

```
blocks.RemoveAll(block=>block.Row == i);
```

Two lines of code. No loops. Clearly correct.

If you don't write any loops then you won't make mistakes in your loop conditions.

Comment: Yes, and if you don't write any computer programs, you won't make mistakes in your programs ;)